# Storing value for page check, navigating to next page, then coming back through link fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**EDIT:** I solved the problem for now, but if anyone could tell me if there is another way or why it was not working before please let me know!

I have a page that is receiving an id from the previous page, based on that id you can look at a person's class schedule.  I have added a link on the class schedule page to take them back to the register for classes page, but I get an error everytime that there is no id.  I'm storing the id in a hidden field but for some reason it is not being passed along with the link.  Not sure why the value is not being passed as it is the same code for the other pages.  Thanks for any help!

Here is the code for the register page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Course Listings</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Aqua Don's Scuba School</h1>
<h2>Class Registration Form</h2>
<?php
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password")
    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
$DBName = "scuba_school";
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
    Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
$DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];
if (empty($DiverID))
    exit("<p>You must enter a diver ID! Click your browser's Back button to return to the previous page.</p>");
$TableName = "divers";
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName WHERE diverID='$DiverID'";
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
    Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult) == 0)
    die("<p>You must enter a valid diver ID! Click your browser's Back button to return to the Registration form.</p.");
mysqli_close($DBConnect);
?>
<form method="get" action="ReviewSchedule.php">
<p><strong>Student ID: <?= $DiverID ?></strong>
<input type="submit" value=" Review Current Schedule " /><input type="hidden" name="diverID" value="<?= $DiverID ?>" /></p>
</form>
<form method="get" action="RegisterDiver.php">
<p><strong>Select the class you would like to take:</strong><br />
<input type="radio" name="class" value="Beginning Open Water" checked="checked" />Beginning Open Water<br />
<input type="radio" name="class" value="Advanced Open Water" />Advanced Open Water<br />
<input type="radio" name="class" value="Rescue Diving" />Rescue Diving<br />
<input type="radio" name="class" value="Divemaster Certification" />Divemaster Certification<br />
<input type="radio" name="class" value="Instructor Certification" />Instructor Certification</p>
<p><strong>Available Days and Times:</strong><br />
<select name="days">
<option selected="selected" value="Mondays and Wednesdays">Mondays and Wednesdays</option>
<option value="Tuesdays and Thursdays">Tuesdays and
Thursdays</option>
<option value="Wednesdays and Fridays">Wednesdays and
Fridays</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
<option selected="selected" value="9 a.m. - 11 a.m.">9 a.m. - 11 a.m.</option>
<option value="1 p.m. - 3 p.m.">1 p.m. - 3 p.m.</option>
<option value="6 p.m. - 8 p.m.">6 p.m. - 8 p.m.</option>
</select><input type="hidden" name="diverID" value="<?= $DiverID ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Register " action="RegisterDiver.php"/>
<input type="reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
<footer>
<div align="center">
    <a href="Registration.html">Return to Registration</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="../Menu.html">Return to Menu</a>
</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the review schedule page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Review Schedule</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Aqua Don's Scuba School</h1>
<h2>This is your current schedule:</h2>
<?php
$DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];
if (empty($DiverID))
    exit("<p>You must enter a diver ID! Click your browser's Back button to return to the previous page.</p>");
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students","password")
    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
$DBName = "scuba_school";
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
    Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
$TableName = "registration";
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName WHERE diverID='$DiverID'";
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
    Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult) == 0)
    die("<p>You have not registered for any classes! Click your browser's Back button to return to the previous page.</p>");
echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Class</th><th>Days</th>
<th>Time</th></tr>";
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
do {
    echo "<tr><td>{$Row['class']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['days']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['time']}</td></tr>";
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
} while ($Row);

?>


<form method="get" action="CourseListings.php">
<input type="hidden" name="diverID" value="<?= $DiverID ?>" />
<center>
<h3><a href="CourseListings.php">Return to View Course Listings</a></h3>
<h3><a href="Registration.html">Go back to Registration</a></h3>
<h3><a href="../Menu.html">Return to Menu</a></h3>
</center>
</form>

<?php
mysqli_free_result($QueryResult);
mysqli_close($DBConnect);
?>


</body>
<footer>
<div align="center">
&copy; Copyright Ryan Strouse &copy;
</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

I figured it out! I need to have:

```
<h3><a href="CourseListings.php?diverID=<?php echo $DiverID;?>">Return to View Course Listings</a></h3>
```

instead of the plain link.  Unless someone comes up with something better? I feel like it should accept everything as is

Answer (score 0):

Use POST instead of GET.

My personal rule of thumb: POST for forms, GET for variables passed thru URL.